# session flush is not working django

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to flush all session data out when a user doesn't want to keep logged in.

in views.py

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if not request.POST.has_key('remember_me'):      
            request.session.flush()

    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But when I try to access the site, it still shows the user as the user logged in. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, if the user doesn't check `Remember me` - you need to *expire the session cookies if user's browser is closed*.

This can be achieved using [`set_expiry(0)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry):

> Sets the expiration time for the session. You can pass a number of different values:
>
> - ...
> - If value is 0, the user’s session cookie will expire when the user’s Web browser is closed.

Usage:

```
request.session.set_expiry(0)
```

See also:

- [Django Remember Me Option at Sign In](http://chriskief.com/2013/09/29/django-remember-me-option-at-sign-in/)

Comment: That's what I meant, but set_expiry(0) didn't work as what I meant. The default value is 300s, 5 mins, is that correct? and has an issue with Chrome. It shows user when reopening. So, I try to use a different way.

Comment: @user2307087 understood. Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings.

Comment: I am using standard settings so here it is.  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (   
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',   
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

Comment: @user2307087 I needed to make sure the `SessionMiddleware` is activated. Ok, do you have `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` and `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE ` settings defined?

Comment: I have set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER = True , SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60*60*24*7*4  (4 weeks).

Comment: If this doesn't work, I will be trying the key to delete it from django_session, but how would I do this?

Comment: @user2307087 just for the testing purposes, could you comment out `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, restart the web server and check if there is a difference? Thanks.

Comment: It's the same, still showing the user on the main page. Now the session cookie age is the default 1209600. The problem with Chrome is the Chrome's setting, which continue reopening. I don't want to use to adjust it..so I'll see another way. Thanks.

Comment: session.flush() is deleting the current key and updating the record with a new key, so this is not working in some way.

Comment: @user2307087 could you also check if the behavior is consistent across different browsers? Thanks.

Comment: No, it worked with FF, IE, just problem with Chrome (chrome's setting).

Comment: @user2307087 thank you, I'll leave the answer as is for others to use the information in it and the discussion in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might have tried this already, but if you are using `django.contrib.auth.views`, then you could try calling [`django.contrib.auth.logout(request)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) to log out the user if they do not want to be remembered, then login as per your existing code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if not request.POST.has_key('remember_me'):
            saved_user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
            logout(request)
            if saved_user is not None:
                request.user = saved_user

    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This should work because `django.contrib.auth.login()` is called behind the scenes. The documentation says that the session is cleared out.

Comment: No, it's not working. I'll set the expiry to 1 sec. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to solve that issue i think is to use
`django-session-security`
it warns user before loging user out
and it starts counting session from the last in activeness(eg: screen movement) of the user.